# No ingresar espacios en blanco en textbox C#

Tags: c#

Tengo un problema, cuando valido que `txtName` y `txtPhone` sean diferentes a "" funciona, pero si ingreso 2 espacios por ejemplo, me lo guarda como vacío, necesito una propiedad que no deje que se guarden en blanco, pero, si ingreso "Juan Perez" que si me cuente el espacio en blanco entre las dos, pero si se ingres "           " que no me lo guarde, ¿Alguna solución?

Comment: Por favor, pon lo que tienes hecho para poderte ayudar

Comment: Utilizal a funcion Trim() <-- esta puede ser aplicada a cualquier string, antes de guardar el dato, o al momento de validarlo.

Answer (score 2):

Has de usar un método que implementa el tipo string; el siguiente código lo ilustra:

```
string MiCadena = "  Ejemplo ";
string SinEspacios = Micadena.Trim();
```

La variable SinEspacios ahora contiene el valor "Ejemplo".

Saludos.